# How to get value of a field based on the other selected values of field on the same form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, forms

Suppose there are two fields in an Html form

Model Number : *DropDown*
Price : *TextBox*

I want to retrieve the value of "Price" field from the database on the basis of selection of a model number from the dropdown without submitting the form.
I am working on spring mvc, so i have to call a method in a controller that will serve me the value of Price field through database.Kindly help me with the UI part.

Comment: please show / post what you have tried

Comment: In a nut shell: populate your dropdown with modelnames and ids. Onchange make a ajax call with the id to a php page. This page should return the price. On success put the returned value in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Controller method : suppose to access form page you need to go /form

```
@RequestMapping(value="/form")
public String showForm(Model model) {

    List<ModelNumbers> list=getList();//getList is method which gets list of model numbers from db

    model.addAttribute("modelNumbers",list);
    return "form";
}
```

In jsp you can access model using expressions or jsp code :

```
    <%

    List<ModelNumbers> list=(List<ModelNumbers>)request.getAttribute("modelNumbers");
    out.print("<select name='modelNumber'>");
    for(ModelNumbers u:list)
    {
        out.print("<option >"+u.getNumber()+"</option>");
    }
    out.print("</select>");

%>
```

or you can use expressions in jsp